# how to create a .swf file with video controls on it, with out any coding?

Tags: flash

how to create a `.swf` file with video controls on it, with out any coding?

Answer (score 1):

To create a video file you use an encoder like FFmpeg. To play the file from a website, you use a flash-based player, such as flowplayer ( http://flowplayer.org ).